# Is there diagnostics output of regsvcs.exe?

Tags: .net, com, com+

can the regsvcs.exe used in a way that there's some sort of diagnostics output? A call doesn't work and I'm not able to see why!

Comment: Which error do you get? The only thing I can find is this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kh40t55h(v=vs.80).aspx . It specifies some errors you can receive.

Comment: I get a "System.EnterpriseServices.RegistrationException: Fehler beim Konfigurieren von Komponenten". 

with HRESULT -2146233087 which is "COR_E_SYSTEM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should see some error log in the Event Viewer, but I remember they are not very descriptive either. [Activating the Fuslog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) could help you to trace a possible assembly binding problem.